# How to print rows from database via ajax and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm newbie in php and JavaScript, and I want to print all rows in my table

I use this code, it works but no output have come from it, and no errors occurs

```
function show(){//function get data and send it to Ajax, and I can make 1 function get 3 parameters 
    //   var formData = new FormData();
    //  formData.append('result', $(("#a").val()));//php elem , html element
    //  formData.append('contactUsEmail', $("#contactUsEmail").val());
    //  formData.append('contactUsMessage', $("#contactUsMessage").val());
    if(false){
        swal("Attention !", "Please fill in all fields", "error");
    }else  {
        //Ajax 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var text =this.responseText; // 0 unvalid , 1 true
                // document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }       
        }

        ajax.open("GET", "one.php", true);
        ajax.send(formData);
    }
}
```

php code here :

```
<?php
function OpenCon()
{
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $db = "chat";
    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);

    return $conn;
}

function show(){
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM masseges";
    $result = OpenCon()->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: ". $row["id"]."bb";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    OpenCon()->close();
 }
```

No errors in page, but a blank page. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Where do you call the PHP functions? And if you add  `console.log(this.responseText);` in the callback function, what do you get in the console?

Comment: If this is the `one.php` file, then note it merely *defines* the functions and never calls them. That is, maybe all you need to do is add the line `show();` at the bottom of the PHP file to actually call the function `show`... :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually returning any html tags back to your website.
You should be able to see the result from the php echo in the network tab of your development console.

If you want to fill a table, I suggest you create the table structure on your website and add the data from php as a new table row.
HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

PHP:

```
echo "<tr><td>id: ". $row['id']."bb</td></tr>";
```

Another word of advide:
Have a look at jquery! Gonna save you a a lot of time!
I have been where you are half a year ago :-)